# flutter web: how to connect to a rest API or localhost

Tags: rest, flutter, browser, flutter-web

My code:

```
void checkState() async {
    print("CTC");
    var url = "http://localhost:3000";
    try {
       var respX = await http.get(url);
    } catch (err) {
      print("response Arrived: $err");
   }
  }
```

But it is not possible:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43015#issuecomment-543835637

I am using google chrome for debugging. simply pasting http://localhost:3000 allows me to connect to the URL from the same browser.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not with the flutter. It is the CORS policies in the browser as well as the server that blocked the request. I hosted it in a nodejs server with express. Here what I have did to solve this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

You can change the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to the domain you are calling from if you want to. Else it will allow request from everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, the localhost of your emulator is not the localhost of your machine. To test the API running on your machine you have to point to the ip adress of your computer

Comment: emulator? in flutter-web?

Comment: I can connect to the url from the same browser from a different tab. Please consider the response from flutter on the github issue link before answering.